# Method links do not exist on Laravel pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-pagination

I'm trying to achieve pagination and it is working absolutely fine until I add *`sortByDesc()`* along with my eloquent query.

**web.php (route file)**

```php
Route::get('/', function(){
  $posts = Post::simplePaginate(5)->sortByDesc("post_id"); 
  //sortByDesc("post_id") this causes the problem
}
```

When I prepare the view for the pagination with `{{ $posts->links() }}` in the specified view, I get the following error-

> Method links does not exist

If I remove the sorting condition from the query, it works perfectly.

What can be the reason behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting the sort on the query rather than the pagination:

```
Post::orderBy('post_id', 'desc')->simplePaginate(5);
```

Answer (score 3):

To extend to what @RossWilson said.

`sortBy` is a collection function, not an eloquent function, the correct eloquent function is `orderBy`.

Also, see `simplePaginate()` as if you were performing a `get(), first(), find()`.

What would you place first the get or the order? ... maybe the get if you want to order a collection (with `sortBy`), but since `simplePaginate` does not return the same collection that a `get()` would return, `sortby` does not work. And probably messes up the pagination object/collection.